# purrr::discard How to delete elements in a vector containing one or more specific strings

Tags: r, purrr

I would like to remove the elements containing '_1' and '_3' in the vector using the `discard` function from `purrr`. Here the example:

```
library(purrr)
x <- c("ABAC_13", "ZDRF73", "UYDS_12", "FGSH41", "GFSC_35" , "JHSC_29")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `discard` we need to provide a logical vector indicating which values we need to discard.

To create a logical vector we use `grepl` giving TRUE values to the elements which have '_1' or '_3'

```
library(purrr)
discard(x, grepl("_1|_3", x))

#[1] "ZDRF73"  "FGSH41"  "JHSC_29"
```

and as @Lazarus Thurston commented using `str_subset` should be a better choice here.

```
str_subset(x, '_(1|3)', negate = TRUE)
```

Comment: Btw stringr::str_subset(x, "_1|_3",negate=T)  should accomplish the same. Not sure if this is faster than discard. And discard with grepl is not pipe friendly.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Thanks @LazarusThurston for your suggestion. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

As this is specific to `tidyverse`, we can use the syntax specific to it

```
library(tidyverse)
str_detect(x, "_[13]") %>%
                  discard(x, .)
#[1] "ZDRF73"  "FGSH41"  "JHSC_29"
```

If we need to remove the elements

```
grep("_\\d+", x, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
#[1] "ZDRF73" "FGSH41"
```

or if it is specific to 1, 3

```
grep("_[13]", x, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
#[1] "ZDRF73"  "FGSH41"  "JHSC_29"
```

If we need to remove the substring part,

```
sub("_\\d+", '', x)
```

Answer (score 0):

This task can be performed using `grepl()`. Basically we want to find such occurrences that contains `_1` or `_3`. The grepl output is a logical vector of `TRUE/FALSE`. Following that we remove those elements from `x` vector by using a subset and negating opearator i.e. `x[!grepl("_1|_3", x)]`.

```
x <- c("ABAC_13", "ZDRF73", "UYDS_12", "FGSH41", "GFSC_35" , "JHSC_29") 
x[!grepl("_1|_3", x)]
```

Comment: You really want to add some explanations here. Code only answers are very often not very helpful to anybody.